# navigation to a location is not working google glass

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a glass app in which I used Navigation functionality by follow below link :

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware

and the code I used :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DARULISLAM MASJID"));
startActivity(intent);
```

I have attached screenshot also.

here 's the logcat :

```
V/GlassNotification(  573): skipping since notification not whitelisted
I/NavigationService( 7774): START_REDELIVER_INTENT
I/SoftOMXPlugin(  126): Created OMXPlugin : OMX.google.raw.decoder
I/AudioPlayer(  126): mLatencyUs = 176000
I/NavigationService( 7774): onStartCommand: 50 Intent { act=android.intent.actio
n.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DARULISLAM MAS
JID flg=0x400000 cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationService }
V/GlassNotification(  573): Received notification id: 1 packageName: com.google.
glass.maps
V/GlassNotification(  573): skipping since notification not whitelisted
D/dalvikvm( 7774): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1964K, 21% free 10400K/13120K, paused 22m
s+5ms, total 124ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 98ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 88ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 91ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 82ms
I/NavigationManager( 7774): StartNavigating: mode=0
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 97ms
I/NavigationService( 7774): START_REDELIVER_INTENT
D/CardScrollView( 7774): Activating.
E/c       ( 7774): RuntimeException while executing runnable com.google.glass.ma
ps.MapHelper$6@41c5bd48 with executor com.google.common.util.concurrent.t@41f2e1
20
E/c       ( 7774): java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelle
d.
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.canc
ellationExceptionWithCause(SourceFile:393)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync
.getValue(SourceFile:310)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync
.get(SourceFile:290)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(
SourceFile:116)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.MapHelper$6.run(SourceFile:362)

E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.t.execute(SourceFil
e:289)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.a(SourceFile:149)

E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.c.a(SourceFile:134)

E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.canc
el(SourceFile:131)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.k.cancel(SourceFile
:799)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.PlaceCardView.hideMap(SourceFil
e:109)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.PlaceCardView.onDetachedFromWin
dow(SourceFile:117)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.jav
a:12627)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(Vie
wGroup.java:2587)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout(ViewGro
up.java:4027)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:
3971)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.remove
ChildView(CardScrollView.java:1307)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.adjust
ViewHierarchy(CardScrollView.java:1034)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.update
ViewsInternal(CardScrollView.java:1118)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.update
Views(CardScrollView.java:1193)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.onData
Changed(CardScrollView.java:720)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.setAda
pter(CardScrollView.java:1891)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.CardsView.setAdapter(SourceFile
:97)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.DestinationCardsView.setDestina
tions(SourceFile:33)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.NavigationActivity.showDestinat
ionsFromUiThread(SourceFile:847)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.NavigationActivity.access$600(S
ourceFile:74)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.NavigationActivity$10.run(Sourc
eFile:838)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5
045)
E/c       ( 7774):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/c       ( 7774):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCalle
r.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.ja
va:602)
E/c       ( 7774):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/c       ( 7774): Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Future
.cancel() was called.
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync
.complete(SourceFile:379)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync
.cancel(SourceFile:357)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.canc
el(SourceFile:128)
E/c       ( 7774):      ... 27 more
D/dalvikvm( 7774): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 481K, 22% free 10276K/13120K, paused 192ms
, total 193ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 7774): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.950MB for 921616-byte alloca
tion
D/dalvikvm( 7774): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 21% free 11173K/14024K, paused 98ms, t
otal 98ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 109K, 21% free 11167K/14024K, paused 87ms,
 total 88ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 7774): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.940MB for 2097168-byte alloc
ation
D/dalvikvm( 7774): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 18% free 13215K/16076K, paused 102ms,
 total 102ms
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onPause
I/BackgroundMapRenderer( 7774): EglHelper.swap: com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLS
urfaceImpl@5cdbd410
V/FormattingLoggers( 7774): TimingData [count=40, sinceCreation=65441ms, spentLo
gging=1591ms].
D/dalvikvm( 7774): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1079K, 23% free 12409K/16076K, paused 30m
s+28ms, total 287ms
I/NavigationInternal( 7774): New route received: I-680 N
I/BackgroundMapRenderer( 7774): EglHelper.destroySurface: com.google.android.gle
s_jni.EGLSurfaceImpl@5cdbd410
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): Clearing UI
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onNewIntent [intent=Intent { act=android.
intent.action.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DA
RULISLAM MASJID cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationActivity }]
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onNewIntent Intent { act=android.intent.a
ction.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DARULISLAM
 MASJID cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationActivity }
V/FormattingLoggers( 7774): TimingData [count=440, sinceCreation=94102ms, spentL
ogging=664ms].
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): Starting navigation service
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onResume
I/BackgroundMapRenderer( 7774): EglHelper.finish
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onPause
W/InputMethodManagerService(  496): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain
of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41e5ee60 attribute=a
ndroid.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41ec5030, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41ec
fcc8
I/SDCardTileCache( 7774): rgts: Commit inserted 3 tiles totaling 42598 bytes in
83 ms. Number of tiles in DiskCache is now 53
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onNewIntent [intent=Intent { act=android.
intent.action.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DA
RULISLAM MASJID cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationActivity }]
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onNewIntent Intent { act=android.intent.a
ction.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DARULISLAM
 MASJID cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationActivity }
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): Starting navigation service
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onResume
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onPause
D/dalvikvm( 7774): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4995K, 26% free 9462K/12784K, paused 22ms
+19ms, total 434ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 408ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 222ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 202ms
D/dalvikvm( 7774): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 234ms
W/ActivityManager(  496): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onNewIntent [intent=Intent { act=android.
intent.action.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DA
RULISLAM MASJID cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationActivity }]
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onNewIntent Intent { act=android.intent.a
ction.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DARULISLAM
 MASJID cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationActivity }
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): Starting navigation service
I/NavigationActivity[41ba1470]( 7774): onResume
I/NavigationService( 7774): onStartCommand: 51 Intent { act=android.intent.actio
n.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DARULISLAM MAS
JID flg=0x400000 cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationService }
V/GlassNotification(  573): Received notification id: 1 packageName: com.google.
glass.maps
V/GlassNotification(  573): skipping since notification not whitelisted
I/NavigationManager( 7774): StartNavigating: mode=0
I/NavigationService( 7774): START_REDELIVER_INTENT
I/NavigationService( 7774): onStartCommand: 52 Intent { act=android.intent.actio
n.VIEW dat=google.navigation:ll=37.91357,-122.073062&mode=d&title=DARULISLAM MAS
JID cmp=com.google.glass.maps/.NavigationService }
I/NavigationManager( 7774): StartNavigating: mode=0
V/GlassNotification(  573): Received notification id: 1 packageName: com.google.
glass.maps
V/GlassNotification(  573): skipping since notification not whitelisted
I/NavigationService( 7774): START_REDELIVER_INTENT
E/c       ( 7774): RuntimeException while executing runnable com.google.glass.ma
ps.MapHelper$6@420fb818 with executor com.google.common.util.concurrent.t@41e993
e8
E/c       ( 7774): java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelle
d.
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.canc
ellationExceptionWithCause(SourceFile:393)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync
.getValue(SourceFile:310)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync
.get(SourceFile:290)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(
SourceFile:116)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.MapHelper$6.run(SourceFile:362)

E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.t.execute(SourceFil
e:289)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.a(SourceFile:149)

E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.c.a(SourceFile:134)

E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.canc
el(SourceFile:131)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.k.cancel(SourceFile
:799)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.PlaceCardView.hideMap(SourceFil
e:109)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.PlaceCardView.onDetachedFromWin
dow(SourceFile:117)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.jav
a:12627)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(Vie
wGroup.java:2587)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout(ViewGro
up.java:4027)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:
3971)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.remove
ChildView(CardScrollView.java:1307)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.adjust
ViewHierarchy(CardScrollView.java:1034)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.update
ViewsInternal(CardScrollView.java:1118)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.update
Views(CardScrollView.java:1193)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.onData
Changed(CardScrollView.java:720)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.setAda
pter(CardScrollView.java:1891)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.CardsView.setAdapter(SourceFile
:97)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.DestinationCardsView.setDestina
tions(SourceFile:33)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.NavigationActivity.showDestinat
ionsFromUiThread(SourceFile:847)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.NavigationActivity.access$600(S
ourceFile:74)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.glass.maps.NavigationActivity$10.run(Sourc
eFile:838)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
E/c       ( 7774):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5
045)
E/c       ( 7774):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/c       ( 7774):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCalle
r.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.ja
va:602)
E/c       ( 7774):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/c       ( 7774): Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Future
.cancel() was called.
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync
.complete(SourceFile:379)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync
.cancel(SourceFile:357)
E/c       ( 7774):      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.canc
el(SourceFile:128)
E/c       ( 7774):      ... 27 more
```

Now , the problem is that when I start app it shows location's name but navigation is not working. why this is not working help me plz ?

[image]

Comment: Can you better describe what is not working? Does navigation simply sit on that view forever or do you see an error dialog of any type? Can you click on that view to start navigation?

Comment: Works smoothly for me. As mentioned by Brandon, there should be some error logs, info you can find in your logcat.

Comment: Yes, navigation hang on that view and tap on this view does nothing. Does click require to see navigation ?

Comment: And I also noticed that the navigation activity is starting up multiple times.

Comment: i have added logcat in question.